# Polynomial alternative algebra

Tags: nonassociative-algebras

Let $F[x]$ be an polynomial alternative algebra over a field $F$. How I compute the universal multiplication envelope of $F[x]$?

Comment: A reference for people who have never heard of this structure : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternative_algebra